# How can I do this calculation without opening the same file twice?

Tags: python, algorithm

I've got a bunch of txt files: `A.txt`, `B.txt`, etc. With each file, I can calculate a variable `varA`, `varB`, etc. I then want to take the difference of these variables, select the 10 combinations whose differences are smallest, and use those txt files to perform even more calculations. The new calculations require both relevant files. For example, suppose the first calculation finds that `A.txt` and `B.txt` have the smallest difference. The new calculation then requires a column from `A.txt` and a column from `B.txt`

How can I do this without opening the txt files several times?

The brute-force approach would be to calculate the difference first, sort it, and then reopen the files again to do the new calculations

```
varList = []
DifferenceList = []

for f in files:
  read_csv(f)
  var = #do calculations
  varList.append(var)

for i in range(1,len(f))
  for j in range(i, len(f))
    difference = varList(i) - varList(j)
    DifferenceList.append(difference, i, j)

DifferenceList.sort()
#Extract indices, make smaller new_list_of_files using the best elements of DifferenceList

for i in range(1, len(new_list_of_files))
  read_csv(new_list_of_files[i])
  for j in range(i, len(new_list_of_files))
    read_csv(new_list_of_files[j])
    #Do calculations using both new_list_of_files[i] and new_list_of_files[j]
```

But this seems very inefficient - I have to open the .txt files twice, and since they are very big files, it's very time consuming.

Comment: Is the second time you "Do calculations" different from what is stored in `var`? About how many files are in `files` and about how big are they? Can they fit in memory?

Comment: @Matt yes to the first question. The new calculations are different from the old ones. As for the number of ````files````, it can be up to several thousand, and definitely will not all fit in memory.

Comment: Your code uses neither `difference` nor `DifferenceList`. Weird.

Comment: Why/how do you have two nested loops at the end?

Comment: @KellyBundy I see what you mean. Fixed the pseudocode.

Comment: Have you considered using pandas?

Comment: @Barmar can you elaborate?

Comment: Read each file into a pandas dataframe, then use dataframe operations to manipulate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what type of calculations you are doing, but I would suggest opening each file once, and gathering the all the data you need before doing the calculations.

Then you can store the information in a dictionary, which is a datastructure that allows you to set a value associated with a certain key. E.g. a filename:

```
import random

def get_data_for_var_calc():
    return random.randint(1,50)

def get_data_for_other_calc():
    return random.randint(1, 50)

def do_calc1(data_1):
    return data_1 * 2

def do_calc2(i,j):
    print(f"i: difference:{i[0]} filename1: {i[1]} filename2: {i[2]}")
    print(f"j: difference:{j[0]} filename1: {j[1]} filename2: {j[2]}")

filenames = ["file1","file2","file3","file4","file5"]
DifferenceList = []
data_dict = {} # define the dictionary object
for filename in filenames:
    # with open(filename, 'r') as file_ptr:
    #     raw_file = file_ptr.read()
    data_1 = get_data_for_var_calc()
    data_2 = get_data_for_other_calc()

    var = do_calc1(data_1)  # do calculations with data_1
    data_dict[filename] = (data_1, data_2, var) # Save var, data1 if you need it and data2

for filename1, value1 in data_dict.items():
    for filename2, value2 in data_dict.items():
        if filename1 == filename2:
            continue # skip comparing the same data
        var1 = value1[2]
        var2 = value2[2]
        difference = var1-var2
        DifferenceList.append((difference, filename1, filename2))

DifferenceList.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

best_data_2 = DifferenceList[:3] # pick lowest three differences

for best_i in best_data_2:
    for best_j in best_data_2:
        do_calc2(best_i, best_j)
```

The dictionary.items() method allows users to iterate over each key/value pair of the dictionary. `data_dict` has filenames as its keys, and a list: [data1, data2, var] as the value associated with the key.

Comment: OP says it cant all be in memory due to the size.

Comment: OP says the files can't be in memory, but if they load them one by one, extract the needed data, I would imagine they could fit... otherwise I don't know how they do anything at all

Comment: The txt files have six columns and several hundred thousand rows. For the second calculation I need one of the columns. I probably can't extract and store a column for a thousand txt files, can I?

Comment: Maybe I can take the data, store it in a new .txt file, and open that when it comes time to do the second calculation (??)

Comment: It depends on the data and how much RAM you have access to. Assuming the data is integers, if you have 100,000 rows per file and 1000 files, you're looking at 3-4 GB of RAM given Python ints are larger than primitives in other languages. These types of problems are interesting to me, so if you need any more specific help, feel free to ask.

Comment: I wound up sorting the files using two indices (a,b), opening (a), and then running through all indices (b) before moving on to the next value of (a). Not ideal, I still have to open (b) again for the next value of (a), but it's acceptably fast.